# Can we group sum in previous period in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to group sum in from previous period in SQL. Here's my data from simplified customer (customer A, B, and C)

```
Customer      Year     Month    Order
A             2019         5       10 
A             2019         4        5
A             2019         3        3
A             2019         2        1 
A             2018        12        3
B             2019         5        1
B             2019         4        2
B             2019         3        1
C             2019         5        2
C             2019         4        1
C             2019         2        1
C             2019         1        3
```

Expected output is sum Order for previous period

For example, Expected output in first row is 12, because it sum in previous period (7 + 4 + 3 + 0) in customer A.

Another example, Expected output in second row is 7 because it sum in previous period (4 + 3 + 0) in customer A. So, table below is the expected output from table above

```
Customer      Year     Month    Order    Output
A             2019         5       10        12
A             2019         4        5         7
A             2019         3        3         4
A             2019         2        1         3
A             2018        12        3         0
B             2019         5        1         3
B             2019         4        2         1
B             2019         3        1         0
C             2019         5        2         5
C             2019         4        1         4
C             2019         2        1         3
C             2019         1        3         0
```

I need to do this in SQL

Comment: could you explain a little more what exactly your formula is for calculating the output? I don't think i realy get it. I mean if you would calculate the sum of all previous output's you would never even reach the first 3 in mont 2 for customer A.

Comment: @MaximVA I try to be more detail, is that enough?

Comment: But then how do you expext the value to be 4 for month 3 (customer A)? 3 + 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i would change the name of your columns (year, month and order are mysql reserved words or functions). You could do it with a subquery like this:

```
select customer, 
       `year`, 
       `month`, 
       `order`, 
        (select sum(output)
         from yourtable b 
         where a.customer=b.customer and (a.year>b.year or (a.year=b.year and a.month>b.month)))
from yourtable a
```

What you do is you get every row and the last column is the sum of output for all other columns with the same customer and have year lower than the year in your customer or if the year is the same, the month is lower

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you should use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(output) over (partition by customer order by year, month)
from t;
```

Note only is this more concise, but it should have better performance as well.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by Window Functions. Below link provides the example

LAG([,offset[, default_value]]) OVER (
    PARTITION BY expr,...
    ORDER BY expr [ASC|DESC],...
)

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/